# MongoDB how do I use $set and $aggregate to set field of nested documents?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to write an expression that allows me to set the field `checked` of my items nested within an other document. How can I achieve this in MongoDB?

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55081de2162072120758fc53")[ 
 {
  "_id": "55081de2162072120758fc53",
  "items": [
   {
    "checked": false,
    "name": "Apples",
    "_id": "554df987a8e9950134aa72bd"
   },
   {
    "checked": false,
    "name": "Jam",
    "_id": "554df98ba8e9950134aa72be"
   }
  }
 ]
 ...
 }
```

In order to access a single item I do the following:

```
xy.aggregate([
  {$match: {_id: new ObjectId(idlist)}},
  {$unwind: '$items'},
  {$match: {'items._id': new ObjectId(iditem)}},
  {$project: {_id: false, item: '$items'}}
```

- **How can I write a query that allows me to set the `Apples` item to `false`?**
- **And is there an easier way to write the aggregation query above?**

Comment: Thanks. This one helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it myself:

```
 db.xy.update({_id: ObjectId("55081de2162072120758fc53"), "items._id": ObjectId("554df987a8e9950134aa72bd")}, {$set: { "items.$.checked": true}}
```